# SQL Server 2008 Express Automatic Backup Methods?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

i would like to ask you about the available automatic backup methods for SQL Server 2008 Express Editition.
I tried Replication method on other server, but it is not available with Express Edition.
Please help, i searched a lot for solutions but nothing found.
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution.. very easy and practical one.

Create the following File : **"SQL_StoredProcedure.sql"**

```
USE MyDBName
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- ============================================= 
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp_BackupDb]  
       @dbName sysname, @backupTypeToRun CHAR(1) 
AS 
BEGIN 
       SET NOCOUNT ON; 

       DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000) 
       DECLARE @dateTime NVARCHAR(20) 

       SELECT @dateTime = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),111),'/','-') +'-' +
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),108),':','')  

       DECLARE @databaseFileName NVARCHAR(200)
       SET @databaseFileName = replace(@dbName,']','')
       SET @databaseFileName = replace(@databaseFileName,'[','')

       IF @backupTypeToRun = 'F' 
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @dbName + 
               ' TO DISK = ''D:\DBBackup\DBs\' + @databaseFileName + '_Full_' + @dateTime + '.BAK''' 

       IF @backupTypeToRun = 'D' 
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @dbName + 
               ' TO DISK = ''D:\DBBackup\DBs\' + @databaseFileName + '_Diff_' + @dateTime + '.BAK'' WITH DIFFERENTIAL' 

       IF @backupTypeToRun = 'L' 
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP LOG ' + @dbName + 
               ' TO DISK = ''D:\DBBackup\DBs\' + @databaseFileName + '_Log_' + @dateTime + '.TRN''' 

       EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand 
END
```

Create the Following File: **"BackupScript.sql"**

```
Use master
Exec mysp_BackupDbMaster 'MyDBName', 'F';
Go
```

Now you have everything. Just create a task in **Windows Task Scheduler**
In the Task itself -> Actions -> Start Program -> Edit, use following inputs:

*Program/script:* `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE`
*Add arguemtns:*  `-S MyServer\MySQlInstant  -E -i D:\DBBackup\BackupScript.sql`